# Install shell extension conditionally

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge, shell-extensions, appx, desktop-app-converter

Reference: Integrate a packaged desktop app with File Explorer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/integrate-packaged-app-with-file-explorer

I now know how to install a shell extension custom menu item in the File Explorer for my win32 packaged desktop app. But I want to give a choice to the user whether he really wants the shell extension. Is there a way to do that in Appx manifest?

Comment: You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iexplorercommandstate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iexplorercommandstate

Comment: I was able to use this work around successfully. Please add this as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around that issue if you implement the [IExplorerCommandState interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iexplorercommandstate) which has the [IExplorerCommandState::GetState method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-iexplorercommandstate-getstate)

> Implement this interface when you need to determine the command state
> dynamically (for instance, based on an item's properties). This
> interface provides the same functionality as
> IExplorerCommand::GetState, without the overhead of that interface's
> additional methods. Implement IExplorerCommandState when you only need
> to compute the command state

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft removed the option to customize the install GUI of an MSIX, this means you cannot create a custom option where your users choose if they want the shell extension or not.

Therefore, the appxmanifest schema does not support the conditional installation of the shell extension, from what I know of.

Microsoft recommends moving all options configurations inside your application, including EULA and license registration procedures. So, theoretically you could try to add the shell registration from your application - I never tried this but maybe the links above from Simon Mourier will help.

Comment: Thanks. This certainly helped. I have described my problem in the comment below Simon's.